# How to use the Wordpress Rest API to Post comments to a Wordpress website in C#?

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, xamarin.forms, wordpress-rest-api

I am developing an application in Xamarin forms shared that uses the rest API, the only problem so far is that for some reason when i try to post a new comment it doesn't appear in the Website platform

```
public async Task<String> SendCommentAsync(Commentary comment, String id)
    {
        String credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("admin:admin"));
        String Reply = "";


        Uri url = new Uri(string.Format("http://wordpresswebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments"+"?post="+id+ "&author_name="+ comment.UserName + "&Authentication=" + credentials + "&content=" + comment.Content + "&parent=" + comment.Parent, string.Empty));
        Console.WriteLine("url : " + url);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        try
        {
            //POST resquest
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url,content);
            Reply = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            String StrContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Content Return : " + StrContent );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }
        return Reply;
    }
}
```

here is the response with status OK:

```
[]
```

I also tried to use Postman to test the request, but the same happens http://wordpresswebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/comments?author_name=SpartaName&content=comment&authorization=20am9hb2FscG9pbTpqb2FvNjE0MzUy&post=59

is there any obligatory parameters that i have to include or is my request bad in itself?

Comment: umm... seems like you've pass the data as url params not in the post body.

Comment: i tried the 2 ways (as params and post body) and both returned the same @Anthony

Comment: if you're using postman, make sure you set the body as raw

Comment: hadn't done that but it didn't change the outcome @Anthony

Comment: Can you take a screenshot?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hqbhin
http://prntscr.com/hqbhq7
http://prntscr.com/hqbi06
 @Anthony

Comment: paste this to the body of your postman request:
{"post":59, "author_name":"SpartaName","author_email":"this@gmail.com","content":"comment"}

choose RAW as the type, then get rid of the other params in your header except for your auth.
POST as the method...
im not sure if you need to urlencode the @ character, likely not.

Comment: didn't change the result :/ still no comment in the admin section @Anthony

Comment: What's the response from the API?...i'll try my local wordpress instance.

Comment: as i say in the question the response is [] @Anthony